# Organize chart with apexchart

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I am using apexchart to do a dashboard but I only can play with width and heigh. 
How can I do more ?
I would like to place my graphs on top, on the left, ect... 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: As it stands, this question is pretty vague and open-ended. Can you add some code examples of what you have done so far?